# Setter-getter functionality fails in a PHP class

Tags: php, class

I'm new to PHP and wrote this code, that includes a class and two instances. The class contains a setter and getter methods to access a private `title` property to display it per instance, when all title words are capitalized by `ucwords()` function. It also contains an "authors" property in that context.

When I execute the code, I get nothing (neither the `title` nor the `author`), also, there aren't any errors so I don't know what I did wrong (I do it as part of a personal exercise when learning in teamtreehouse.com).

```
class Recipe {
    private $title;
    public $author = "Me myself";

    public function setTitle($title) {
        echo $this->title = ucwords($title);
    }
    public function getTitle($title) {
        echo $this->title;
    }
}

$recipe1 = new Recipe();
    $recipe1->getTitle("chinese tofu noodles");
    $recipe1->author;

$recipe2 = new Recipe();
    $recipe2->getTitle("japanese foto maki");
    $recipe2->author = "A.B";
```

<sub>Note: AFAIU from the video in teamtreehous.com, a setter-getter functionality is needed if we want to access a private property.</sub>

Why is nothing printed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

class Recipe {

    private $title;
    public $author = "Me myself";

    /* Private function for set title */
    private function setTitle($title) {
        echo $this->title = ucwords($title);
    }

    /* public function for get title */
    public function getTitle($title) {
        $this->setTitle($title);
    }
}

$recipe = new Recipe(); // creating object 
    $recipe->getTitle("chinese tofu noodles"); // calling function 
    echo "<br>";
    echo $recipe->author;

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You mixed up getters, setters and `echo`. Getters should not accept arguments and return properties. Setters accept argument and set property. `echo` outputs (text)string to the screen.

Documentation for [echo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php).

```
class Recipe {
    private $title;
    public $author = "Me myself";

    public function setTitle($title) {
        $this->title = ucwords($title);
    }

    public function getTitle() {
        return $this->title;
    }
}
$noodles = new Recipe();
$noodles->setTitle("chinese tofu noodles");
echo ($noodles->getTitle);
//outputs 'chinese tofu noodles'
```

Answer (score 0):

You've never **set** the title of the object. You've used the **get** function which just prints out nothing in this case.

Adjustment

```
<?php
$recipe1 = new Recipe();
//set the title
$recipe1->setTitle("chinese tofu noodles");
//get the title
$recipe1->getTitle();
```

In your scenario you don't need to an argument for the get function.

Answer (score 0):

In your two recipes examples, you never set the title as you're calling getTitle.
Also, getTitle doesn't need an argument as you don't use it in your function.

For the author, you simply doesn't print anything.

This code should work:

```
class Recipe {
    private $title;
    public $author = "Me myself";
    public $ingredients = array();
    public $instructions = array();
    public $tag = array();

    public function setTitle($title) {
        echo $this->title = ucwords($title);
        echo $this->author;
    }
    public function getTitle() { // Removing parameter as it's unused
        echo $this->title;
    }
}

$recipe1 = new Recipe();
    $recipe1->setTitle("chinese tofu noodles"); // set the title
    $recipe1->getTitle(); // print the title
    echo $recipe1->author; // Will print "Me myself"

$recipe2 = new Recipe();
    $recipe2->setTitle("japanese foto maki"); // set the title
    $recipe2->getTitle(); // print the title
    echo $recipe2->author = "A.B"; // Will print "A.B"
```